# Shibboleth has a local "user store"?

Tags: authentication, store, claims-based-identity, shibboleth

I want to have own identity provider in my website. I don't want use another identity provider like google, yahoo and etc for OpenID connect (For registration of my website).
I think Shibboleth is good and stable solution for this require. But I don't sure about it:
1- Shibboleth is only identity layer and don't have any database for store users attribute, this mean, I should have another solution for store my user's attribute and using shibboleth only for SSO and authentication.
2- I can use shibboleth for both of the SSO/authentication and "user's attribute store"

Answer (score 3):

First I have questions for you.

1. Do you want to use any other authentication provider for you application?
2. Do you want to give authentication/authorization to any other web site?
3. Do you have or will have multiple application which will need single point sign one ?

If the answer to any of above question is false then you don't need Shibboleth.

You need to first understand how shibboleth works. There are two main product in shibboleth **Service Provider** and **Identity Provider**. If your case is point 1 then you need SP, if your case is point 2 then you need idP and if your case is point 3 then you need both.

idP and SP are totally disjoint things. In case of you logging in into stackoverflow using google's account, google is idP and stackoverflow is SP.

idP manages authentication, so it will have the user database/data, So answering to your first question, **yes shibboleth does not have any database** to store user data and it is only identity layer. Or more precisely authorization layer.

Because SP is what that use that authentication to authorize some paths in its website. If you configure your SP in such a way that example.com/secure should only be accessible when user is authenticated in example2.com - authentication - then when user go to example.com/secure, shibboleth will redirect him to example.com/login (configurable in idP) and will only allow to access when shibboleth will have valid session.

Answering to your second question, Yes you can use it both ways but **you should not** because it is authentication/authorization software, it gives some attributes from idP to SP but it is always recommended to use that information and store it in our DB.

*Edit (after reading comment)*

So you definitely need SSO. It need not to have Shibboleth which is SAML based. Choosing a SSO technique is big thing and require lengthy answer. 
I have used OAuth, LDAP, Shibboleth, SAML. I am using OAuth2 for my applications.

Please search for comparison between Shibboleth and OAuth2 and decide. [This](https://www.mutuallyhuman.com/blog/2013/05/09/choosing-an-sso-strategy-saml-vs-oauth2/) may help.

Comment: Thank you for reply, Answer of your question: 1-No 2-Yes 3-Yes

Comment: If I want use shibboleth for authN/authZ in my website, for user store (store username and password and other attribute of users) which software is good solution? note to this: I want give authN/authZ to other website or app.

Comment: I think SSO is a solution between many identity provider (that have a store of users like username and password and other attribute) that trusted each other for single sign on. But I need a idP solution for my own with single point management users (database) that other software use it for their authentication/authorization. I think SSO is more authN/authZ solution (without store/database). I am finding to a solution that have a database for store the identity of users like username/password. I am finding to a identity provider that is my own. If my think is false please guidance me.

Comment: Nope, you are right, You have to create your identity provider.

Comment: You don't know, which software should I use for implementation the my own identity provider?

Comment: Use OAuth2, that is the best currently. Most of the applications provide auth via OAuth, so it is easily connectable.

Comment: OAuth2? with this solution, I 'll become a "identity provider"? where stored username and password of users? please explain more. I think the OAuth2 is only authorization layer and handled identity with OpenID connect. if possible guidance me about it, that how can be an "identity provider" with OAuth2/OpenID

Comment: You can be identity provider or you can use external source. Create your own AUthorization Server or use something like OKTA, AWS Cognito, Azure AD Oauth2, or OpenSource key cloak